# Xts object comparison

Tags: r

Trying to compare xts objects, wanted to ensure that Ret and Ret2 columns are the same.

```
    head(rts.fut)
            Open  High   Low Close Close.prev        Ret       Ret2
2015-01-05 78450 78450 72470 73100         NA         NA         NA
2015-01-06 73230 74900 71000 72760      73100 -0.4651163 -0.4651163
2015-01-08 72800 81380 72800 80190      72760 10.2116548 10.2116548
2015-01-09 80190 81050 74450 77330      80190 -3.5665295 -3.5665295
2015-01-12 77140 77140 73180 74490      77330 -3.6725721 -3.6725721
2015-01-13 74230 74230 70870 73470      74490 -1.3693113 -1.3693113
```

Results:

```
 > head(rts.fut$Ret)==head(rts.fut$Ret2)
             Ret
2015-01-05    NA
2015-01-06 FALSE
2015-01-08 FALSE
2015-01-09 FALSE
2015-01-12 FALSE
2015-01-13 FALSE
```

Any help will be highly appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: Where does your `rts.fut` come from? How can we confirm this if you don't give us a reproducible example? Also there are many more R experts on StackOverflow than there are here, so for simple R questions you will do better posting there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary related to `xts`. You are comparing to floating point values. As pointer out in this [excellent resource](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) these type of comparisons are dangerous. Best way to code it if you do not have `Inf`, `-Inf` or `NaN` is by doing,

```
(abs(rts.fut$Ret - rts.fut$Ret2) / pmin(abs(rts.fut$Ret) + abs(rts.fut$Ret2),
  .Machine$double.eps)) < .Machine$double.eps
```

Hope this helps.